# Testing own OS X framework

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unit-testing, macos

I'm writing my first OS X Objective-C framework, but I do not know how to test it. How can I execute methods and classes in framework for testing purposes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chris Hanson's excellent set of [articles](http://chanson.livejournal.com/119303.html) on setting up unit testing for Frameworks in Xcode is a wonderful reference for testing frameworks. Their content has been largely incorporated (and supplanted) by the article, [Automated Unit Testing with 
Xcode 3 and Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/mac/articles/tools/unittestingwithxcode3.html), on Apples' Dev site.

Answer (score 2):

Make a unit test bundle target, and create test case classes in that bundle. You'll link against the OCUnit framework to get the base classes for your tests; there are a few OCUnit tutorials around, which you can find on Google.

For harder-to-test tasks, such as drawing in views, the easiest way is to make a test app and check the results yourself.

Comment: The Google Toolbox for Mac (on code.google.com) has excellent view and CALayer testing features. Essentially it allows you to automatically compare pixel-by-pixel renderings of either NSView or CALayer instances, failing if there are differences. For testing drawing/UI code, it's a godsend.

Answer (score 1):

You can find several [articles about unit testing](http://chanson.livejournal.com/182472.html) on the blog of [Chris Hanson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714/chris-hanson).

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to create a new executable target that depends on and calls the framework you're using.